# Declaring custom URL schema in manifest causing duplicate application in complete action dialog

Tags: php, android, deep-linking, custom-url

I want to open deep link dialog in my application, so I defined the following in the manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ActivityA"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|stateVisible" >
    <intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="rentaldashboard" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:host="my.site.com" />

        <data android:pathPattern=".*" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    </intent-filter>
```

```
    <activity
    android:name=".ActitivtyB"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|stateVisible" >
    <intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="rentalreset" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:host="my.site.com" />

        <data android:pathPattern=".*" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**ActivityA** and **ActivityB** use the schema and when I run above code it show dialog like below:

[image: Complete action with]

The dialog lists my application logo twice. I want only one logo at a time for both activity open respectively. So any idea how can I make it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have just partial urls like `/user` or `/news` for ActivityA and `/admin` is just for ActivityB then you should improve your path filters. By the way they have to start with a slash and that patters are no regular expressions.

If you want to support a custom scheme and a http(s) url, then you should use multiple intent filters:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ActivityA"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|stateVisible" >
    <intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="https" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:host="dev.worldofrental.com" />
        <data android:host="www.worldofrental.com" />

        <data android:pathPrefix="/urlredirect/getstarted" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="your.package.name"
              android:host="getstarted" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name=".ActitivtyB"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|stateVisible" >
    <intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="https" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:host="dev.worldofrental.com" />
        <data android:host="www.worldofrental.com" />

        <data android:pathPrefix="/urlredirect/resetpassword" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="your.package.name"
              android:host="resetpassword" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Just in general I would suggest to use the package name as scheme to make sure that no other apps will "steal" your intents.

Comment: i try your code but my application icon not showing only install browser is showing popup i tried for ActivityB

Comment: Ya Sure For **ActivityA** [http://dev.worldofrental.com/urlredirect/getstarted](http://dev.worldofrental.com/urlredirect/getstarted) and For **ActivityB** [http://dev.worldofrental.com/urlredirect/resetpassword/0agb3Oj11mnt](http://dev.worldofrental.com/urlredirect/resetpassword/0agb3Oj11mnt)

Comment: See above two urls for both activity

Comment: your code working for my ActivityA but in ActivityB it is not show my application icon , i think for ActivityB my url include urlredirect/resetpassword/0agb3Oj11mnt  , at last it is **0agb3Oj11mnt** it is key which is dynamic that why it is not show my application , so any solution for that?